# Java x64 interface refusing to run

Tags: java

I have a problem with a particular windows installation where any graphical element of java refuses to run.

Java has previously ran successfully on the current Windows installation, but was probably over 12 months ago.

This issue presented itself when I tried to run a .jar and no window ever opened (nothing showing signs of life in task manager).

Clicking 'Java' in control panel results in the 'waiting' cursor for a quarter of a second then nothing.
Running 'About Java' and 'Configure Java' shortcuts also results in this same behavior.

I have tried:

1. Uninstalling Java, rebooting and re-installing the latest x64 version (1.8.0_271)
2. Running 'JavaRa' ([JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/)) in the hopes of cleaning up something that the uninstallation missed
3. Removing '.\Oracle\Java\javapath' from PATH environment variable as suggested by [java x86 stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331073/java-environment-does-not-start-even-in-the-control-panel)

The only signs of life I can get is in powershell/command prompt.

Running java -version results in the output as expected:

```
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
```

However running, `java -jar 'jarfile.jar'`  does not launch the application window.

### Amendment:

I have resorted to trying a fresh copy of Windows installed on a USB drive. I have installed the same x64 version of Java using the same offline installer .exe

Java works normally on this fresh install.

#### Running a .jar on existing windows install

running `java -jar "technicLauncher.jar"` results in

```
Settings for exe: /D:/TechnicLauncher.jar
Portable settings dir: E:\technic
```

At this point, the applications user interface *does not* open, powershell displays: `Setting up logging` then the program exits.

#### Running a .jar on fresh windows install

running `java -jar "technicLauncher.jar"` results in

```
Settings for exe: /D:/TechnicLauncher.jar
Portable settings dir: E:\technic
```

At this point, the applications user interface opens and I can continue as normal.

Comment: What is the error message you get when you execute `java -jar yourFile.jar` from the cmd window?

Comment: Hi @Progman - I have updated my question with further analysis including the answer to your question

Comment: The `java` application successfully starts the JAR executable, as you get messages from the `TechnicLauncher.jar` file/application. Why the application itself is stopping depends on the code of the application. You have to speak with the author of that JAR file what the problem is.

Comment: Hi @Progman, I understand where you are coming from, however I don't believe this is an issue with the particular JAR, I simply used that one for testing. The same behavior is seen with other .JAR files, it would appear to execute 'correctly', but no graphical interface is ever rendered. The same goes for 'Configure Java' and 'About Java' panes. The cursor shows 'busy' for a short time but no interface ever shows.